# My Android studio is not detecting my Android OnePlus 6T device

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, ubuntu, adb

I have installed every SDK in Android studio:
[image]

[image]

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b34f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 2a70:4ee7  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:311d Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here is :

```
$ adb device
List of devices attached
eb048141    no permissions (user in plugdev group; are your udev rules wrong?); see [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html]
```

Here is the User:

```
$ sudo useradd -G plugdev edawking
useradd: user 'edawking' already exists
```

Here is the :

```
$ ls -l /dev/bus/usb/001
total 0
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189,  0 Dec 11 13:23 001
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189,  1 Dec 11 13:23 002
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189,  3 Dec 11 13:23 004
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 10 Dec 11 13:38 011
```

I have even added the 
udev / rule.d / 51-android.rules as well as 70-android.rules as:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666" also,
```

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0e79", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0502", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0b05", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="413c", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0489", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="091e", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="24e3", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2116", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0482", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="17ef", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"    
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0409", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2080", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0955", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2257", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10a9", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d4d", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0471", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04da", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="05c6", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1f53", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04dd", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0930", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

after that I have even change the file permision

```
sudo chmod a+rx /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

Basically, what I have trying to say is that before posting this post I have tried all the troubleshooting mentioned in the link I have shared below.

I have also followed the tutorial from the link mentioned below: [adb devices” command won't detect my 4.4 Android phone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632651/adb-devices-command-wont-detect-my-4-4-android-phone)

as well as the previous resolution from stackoverflow.com : 
[Android studio doesn't detected my android device on my ubuntu laptop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37820656/android-studio-doesnt-detect-my-device-on-my-ubuntu-laptop)

[Adb is not detecting my android device on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151114/adb-is-not-detecting-my-android-device-on-ubuntu)

[Android studio not detecting my USB device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41095995/android-studio-not-detected-my-usb-device-ubuntu)

[ubuntu is not detecting my android device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461729/ubuntu-is-not-detecting-my-android-device)

but none of these resolutions are works. If there is any other solution please share. Need assistance. My Ubuntu version is 19.4. I also want to mentioned that previously it was working when I use the HDD, but recently I have replaced it into SSD since than it was not working I hope thats not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One thing it might be: Enable usb debugging

- Settings
- System
- Developer options
- Turn the setting on for USB  debugging

If it does not appear go to settings about phone. Then click on build number like 7-10 times and it will enable you to have the developer options appear.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`, it must contain:

```
#   OnePlus(Oreo)
ATTR{idVendor}!="2a70", GOTO="not_OnePlus"
ENV{adb_user}="yes"
#       Charging mode
ATTR{idProduct}=="4ee7", SYMLINK+="android_adb"
#       MTP mode
ATTR{idProduct}=="9011", SYMLINK+="android_adb"
#       PTP mode
ATTR{idProduct}=="904e", SYMLINK+="android_adb"
GOTO="android_usb_rule_match"
LABEL="not_OnePlus"
...
#               OnePlus One
ATTR{idProduct}=="676?", SYMLINK+="android_adb"
#               OnePlus Two
ATTR{idProduct}=="9011", SYMLINK+="android_adb"
#               OnePlus 3
ATTR{idProduct}=="900e", SYMLINK+="android_adb"
#               OnePlus 3T
ATTR{idProduct}=="676c", SYMLINK+="android_adb"
#       OnePlus 3T w/ Oreo MIDI mode
ATTR{idProduct}=="90bb", SYMLINK+="android_adb"
#               OnePlus 5 / 6 / 6T
ATTR{idProduct}=="9011", SYMLINK+="android_adb"
#               OnePlus 6 / Asia
ATTR{idProduct}=="f003", SYMLINK+="android_adb"
```

Check it is destected with  `lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 2a70:4ee7 OnePlus Technology (Shenzhen) Co., Ltd. ONEPLUS A3010 [OnePlus 3T] / A5010 [OnePlus 5T] / A6003 [OnePlus 6] (Charging + USB debugging modes)
```

Enable USB debugging on the phone:

1. Enable developer mode (with Android 11)

- Settings
- "About phone"
- 5 taps on "Build number"

2. Enable usb debugging (with Android 11)

- Settings
- System
- Developer Options (fourth from the end)
- Turn the setting on for USB debugging

3. "USB debugging connected" popup while plugged to te computer (with Android 11)

- "Allow" this computer

Test:

```
# adb devices -l
List of devices attached
********               device usb:1-1 product:OnePlus7TPro_EEA model:HD1913 device:OnePlus7TPro transport_id:2
```